# HttpOpenRequest () Wininet c++ e PHP

Tags: php, c, delphi, dll, wininet

I have this code but it is not working. I tested it via Postman and PHP can get the data correctly. The problem is in C++ where it is not sending the file via POST.  What's wrong?

The idea is for the DLL to generate the `.txt` file and POST this file to PHP, where it will receive and insert it into a database.

```cpp
void PHP_Autentication (void){  
    static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"arquivo\"; filename=\"g.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nCodex Anti-Hack\r\n-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk--\r\n";
    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk";
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("MyBrowser",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(!hSession)
    {
        PHP_DC();
    }                           
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T (carrega.IP_Server_and_Hard),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    if(!hConnect)                                      
    { 
        PHP_DC();
    }
    LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST", _T("sentinela/sentinela.php"), NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 1); 
    if(hRequest==NULL)
    {
        PHP_DC();
    }
    BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
    if(!sent)
    {
        PHP_DC();
    }
    char buffer[2048] = {};
    DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    BOOL success = HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, buffer, &bufferSize, NULL);
    if(!success)
    {
        PHP_DC();
    }
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    success = InternetReadFile(hRequest, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bufferSize); 
    if(!success)
    {
        PHP_DC();
    }
    else
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
        InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    }
}
```

The PHP file is this:

```php
<?php
session_start();
define('HOST', '111.111.111.111');
define('USUARIO', 'user');
define('SENHA', 'pass');
define('DB', 'db');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST,USUARIO,SENHA);
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($conexao, DB);

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){

    var_dump($dados);

    $mac = $dados[0];
    $serial = $dados[1];
    $namepc = $dados[2];
    $idgame = $dados[3];
    $ip = $dados[4];
    $userpc = $dados[5];

}   

$sql = "INSERT INTO log (id, user, mac_addr, serial, uName, ip, date) VALUES ('NULL', '$idgame', 
'$mac', '$serial', '$namepc', '$ip', now())";

mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

?>
```

The file to be sent in the POST is a `.txt` containing:

```
00:00:AA:AA:00:00
123456789
DESKTOP-11111
123456789
192.168.0.0
Jhon
```

Comment: Are you compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined or not? You are not really managing your `TCHAR` data properly. You can't use the `_T()` macro with variables, only with literals, so `_T(carrega.IP_Server_and_Hard)` is not valid.  And `(const char*)"POST"` should be `_T("POST")`. And `strlen(hdrs)` should be `_tcslen(hdrs)`. And `frmdata` should NOT be using `TCHAR` at all since MIME is not allowed to use a 16bit Unicode encoding, only a 7bit ASCII encoding

Comment: Since you are able to get the PHP working with Postman, I strongly suggest you use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to capture the raw HTTP data and compare the Postman request to your WinInet request and see what is actually different between them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The character set is: Use the multibyte character set. It is not unicode. 
What should I use on frmdata instead of TCHAR?

Comment: You need to use `char[]` not `TCHAR[]` for `frmdata` as it needs to use 1-byte characters regardless of whether you are compiling for Unicode or MBCS.  But since you are compiling for MBCS than `TCHAR` maps to `char`, so that is not your issue right now. But it is something you need to be aware of when writing code that uses `TCHAR`. Don't mix `char`/`wchar_t`/`tchar` APIs like you are, bad things will happen if you ever change the config later.  You really shouldn't be using `TCHAR` at all, it is an outdated API from the Win9x/ME days.

Comment: That being said, what does `PHP_DC()` do exactly?  Does it do any logging of WinInet errors from `GetLastError()` and `InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`?  You have quite a few places in this code where a failure could occur before PHP gets the data, but you don't indicate where the failure is actually occuring. Have you tried to debug this code yourself yet?

Comment: `void PHP_DC(){
if (carrega.Log_Txt_Hack == 1){
ofstream out("Sentinela/Log.txt", ios::app);
out << "\nHTTP Server connection fail!";
out.close();
}` @RemyLebeau

Comment: That `PHP_DC` code is not even remotely useful at all for diagnosing WinInet failures.  At least add the error code from `GetLastError()` to the output, and maybe the failed function name, too.

Comment: I removed the comment from GetLasError and added a MessageBox to see where it was going and it doesn't really show any error. @RemyLebeau

Comment: if none of the WinInet functions are failing, then either the data being posted is malformed (which it doesn't appear to be), or the server is simply not responding. This goes back to my earlier suggestion to sniff the HTTP traffic  to look for differences between the traffic that Postman and vs what WinInet sends.

Comment: Localhost POST worked, but it is sending to PHP the string: Codex Anti-Hack that comes from `static TCHAR frmdata[] = _T("-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"arquivo\"; filename=\"teste.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nCodex Anti-Hack\r\n-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk--\r\n");` 
The correct thing would be to send the file.txt and PHP to get its contents. @RemyLebeau

Comment: well, that is easy enough. Simply dont use `HttpSendRequest()` to send the MIME data. Use `HttpSendRequestEx()`+`InternetWriteFile()`+`HttpEndRequest()` instead. Send the headers and first 1/2 of the MIME data up to the file content, then use `ReadFile()`+`InternetWriteFile()` to send the file content, then send the rest of the MIME data after the content, then end the request.

Comment: Would you have a simple example or could you show me what the code should look like? Please. I tried to do it with some random examples and I couldn't compile it. @RemyLebeau

Comment: I have posted an answer showing that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a `.txt` file at all.  You are sending a hard-coded string `"Codex Anti-Hack"` in its place.

To send an actual `.txt` file, you can either:

- dynamically allocate the entire MIME data buffer, fill it, and pass it to `HttpSendRequest()`.  Query the file size at runtime to know how large to allocate the buffer.  For example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

struct HINTERNET_deleter
{
    using pointer = HINTERNET;
    // in VC2010: use this instead:
    // typedef HINTERNET pointer;

    void operator()(HINTERNET hInternet) const { InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); }
};

using HINTERNET_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HINTERNET>::type, HINTERNET_deleter>;
// in VC2010: use this instead:
// typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HINTERNET>::type, HINTERNET_deleter> HINTERNET_ptr;

struct HFILE_deleter
{
    using pointer = HANDLE;
    // in VS2010, use this instead:
    // typedef HANDLE pointer;

    void operator()(HANDLE hFile) const { if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(hFile); }
};

using HFILE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, HFILE_deleter>;
// in VS2010, use this instead:
// typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, HFILE_deleter> HFILE_ptr;

bool PHP_Autentication()
{
    static char frmdata_1[] = "-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk\r\n"
                                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"arquivo\"; filename=\"g.txt\"\r\n"
                                "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                                "\r\n";
    static DWORD frmdata_1_len = sizeof(frmdata_1) - 1;

    static char frmdata_2[] = "\r\n"
                                "-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk--\r\n";
    static DWORD frmdata_2_len = sizeof(frmdata_2) - 1;

    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk";
    static DWORD hdrs_len = (sizeof(hdrs) / sizeof(hdrs[0])) - 1;

    HFILE_ptr hFile( CreateFile(_T("path\\filename.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL) );
    if (hFile.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile.get(), NULL);
    if (dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          
    
    std::vector<char> frmdata(frmdata_1_len + dwFileSize + frmdata_2_len);

    std::copy_n(frmdata_1, frmdata_1_len, &frmdata[0]);

    DWORD dwOffset = frmdata_1_len;
    while (dwFileSize > 0)
    {
        DWORD dwNumRead;
        if ((!ReadFile(hFile.get(), &frmdata[dwOffset], dwFileSize, &dwNumRead, NULL)) || (dNumRead == 0))
        {
            // error handling...
            return false;
        }                          

        dwOffset += dwNumRead;
        dwFileSize -= dwNumRead;
    }
    
    std::copy_n(frmdata_2, frmdata_2_len, &frmdata[dwOffset]);

    HINTERNET_ptr hSession( InternetOpen(_T("MyBrowser"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0) );
    if (!hSession)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    HINTERNET_ptr hConnect( InternetConnect(hSession.get(), carrega.IP_Server_and_Hard, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1) );
    if (!hConnect)                                    
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};
    HINTERNET_ptr hRequest( HttpOpenRequest(hConnect.get(), _T("POST"), _T("sentinela/sentinela.php"), NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 1) );
    if (!hRequest)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    if (!HttpSendRequest(hRequest.get(), hdrs, hdrs_len, frmdata.data(), frmdata.size()))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    DWORD dwStatusCode, dwIndex = 0;
    if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest.get(), HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &dwStatusCode, sizeof(dwStatusCode), &dwIndex))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          
    
    TCHAR buffer[2048] = {};
    DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    dwIndex = 0;
    if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest.get(), HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, buffer, &bufferSize, &dwIndex))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    #ifdef UNICODE
    std::ostream &t_cout = std::wcout;
    #else
    std::ostream &t_cout = std::cout;
    #endif
    t_cout.write(buffer, bufferSize / sizeof(TCHAR));
    t_cout << std::endl;

    return ((dwStatusCode / 100) == 2);
}
```

- use [`HttpSendRequestEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequestexw) instead of `HttpSendRequest()`, so that you can use [`ReadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) and [`InternetWriteFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetwritefile) to send the file data in chunks in the middle of the MIME data.  For example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

struct HINTERNET_deleter
{
    using pointer = HINTERNET;
    // in VC2010: use this instead:
    // typedef HINTERNET pointer;

    void operator()(HINTERNET hInternet) const { InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); }
};

using HINTERNET_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HINTERNET>::type, HINTERNET_deleter>;
// in VC2010: use this instead:
// typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HINTERNET>::type, HINTERNET_deleter> HINTERNET_ptr;

struct HFILE_deleter
{
    using pointer = HANDLE;
    // in VS2010, use this instead:
    // typedef HANDLE pointer;

    void operator()(HANDLE hFile) const { if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(hFile); }
};

using HFILE_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, HFILE_deleter>;
// in VS2010, use this instead:
// typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, HFILE_deleter> HFILE_ptr;

bool WriteToInet(HINTERNET hRequest, LPCVOID buffer, DWORD size)
{
    LPCBYTE ptr = (LPCBYTE) buffer;
    DWORD dwNumWritten;
    
    while (size > 0)
    {
        if (!InternetWriteFile(hRequest, ptr, size, &dwNumWritten))
            return false;

        ptr += dwNumWritten;
        size -= dwNumWritten;
    }

    return true;
}

bool PHP_Autentication()
{
    static char frmdata_1[] = "-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk\r\n"
                                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"arquivo\"; filename=\"g.txt\"\r\n"
                                "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                                "\r\n";
    static DWORD frmdata_1_len = sizeof(frmdata_1)-1;

    static char frmdata_2[] = "\r\n"
                                "-----------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk--\r\n";
    static DWORD frmdata_2_len = sizeof(frmdata_2)-1;

    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------og94kfkldjs7ekk";
    static DWORD hdrs_len = (sizeof(hdrs) / sizeof(hdrs[0])) - 1;

    HFILE_ptr hFile( CreateFile(_T("path\\filename.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL) );
    if (hFile.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile.get(), NULL);
    if (dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    HINTERNET_ptr hSession( InternetOpen(_T("MyBrowser"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0) );
    if (!hSession)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    HINTERNET_ptr hConnect( InternetConnect(hSession.get(), carrega.IP_Server_and_Hard, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1) );
    if (!hConnect)                                    
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};
    HINTERNET_ptr hRequest( HttpOpenRequest(hConnect.get(), _T("POST"), _T("sentinela/sentinela.php"), NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 1) );
    if (!hRequest)
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          

    INTERNET_BUFFERS buf;
    ZeroMemory(&buf, sizeof(buf));
    buf.dwStructSize = sizeof(buf);
    buf.lpcszHeader = hdrs;
    buf.dwHeadersLength = hdrs_len;
    buf.dwHeadersTotal = hdrs_len;
    buf.lpvBuffer = NULL;
    buf.dwBufferLength = 0;
    buf.dwBufferTotal = frmdata_1_len + dwFileSize + frmdata_2_len;
    buf.dwOffsetLow = 0;
    buf.dwOffsetHigh = 0;

    if (!HttpSendRequestEx(hRequest.get(), &buf, NULL, 0, 1))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    if (!WriteToInet(hRequest.get(), frmdata_1, frmdata_1_len))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }
    
    BYTE buffer[2048];
    while (dwFileSize > 0)
    {
        DWORD dwNumRead;
        if ((!ReadFile(hFile.get(), buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwNumRead, NULL)) || (dwNumRead == 0))
        {
            // error handling...
            return false;
        }                          

        if (!WriteToInet(hRequest.get(), buffer, dwNumRead))
        {
            // error handling...
            return false;
        }

        dwFileSize -= dwNumRead;
    }

    if (!WriteToInet(hRequest.get(), frmdata_2, frmdata_2_len))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    if (!HttpEndRequest(hRequest.get(), NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwStatusCode, dwIndex = 0;
    if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest.get(), HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &dwStatusCode, sizeof(dwStatusCode), &dwIndex))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }                          
    
    TCHAR buffer[2048] = {};
    DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    dwIndex = 0;
    if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest.get(), HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, buffer, &bufferSize, &dwIndex))
    {
        // error handling...
        return false;
    }

    #ifdef UNICODE
    std::ostream &t_cout = std::wcout;
    #else
    std::ostream &t_cout = std::cout;
    #endif
    t_cout.write(buffer, bufferSize / sizeof(TCHAR));
    t_cout << std::endl;

    return ((dwStatusCode / 100) == 2);
}
```

Comment: @RemyLeabeu Thank you so much for all your help! But when trying to compile, I get some errors. Could it be due to the compiler? I use visual studio 2010. 
I'll leave the link with the image of the errors and the code, in case you can take a look. I will be very grateful.  [https://prnt.sc/uqvx6f] [https://github.com/matheusgratao/Codex/blob/master/Server_Ban.cpp]

Comment: @mgratao There were a few typos, I have fixed them now. But you are also using an old compiler that does not have a full C++11 implementation, in this case it does not support `using` aliases, you will have to change those into `typedef`s instead.

Comment: With that last code it worked! Thank you very much for all your help and patience. 
Just one more question. Only localhost is working. My website is on a shared hosting, so there is no way for me to access it via IP, only via domain. Do you know if you have any other way to use InternetConnect?

Comment: @mgratao `InternetConnect()` will work just fine with hostnames as well as IPs. That is how it is designed to work. If it is not working for you then you are likely not using it correctly. For example, to access `http://server`, set `lpszServerName` to just `"server"` and `dwService` to `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT`. To access `https://server`, set `lpszServiceName` to just `"service"` and `dwService` to `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT`